# How to fix an error with function mod in Sagemath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sage

I have decided to use Sagemath because I have heard that it is very useful in number theory. I have  made this program (it is my first program) to factorise a number and I don't know why it doesn't work. I think that it is related to a specific property of function mod, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks.

```
    #Pollard algorithm
k=87757
f(x)=x^2+1
x=1
y=x
iter=20
i=0
while(i<iter):
    i=i+1
    x=mod(f(x),k)
    y=mod(f(f(y)),k)
    g=(x-y).gcd(k)
    if(1<g and g<k):
        print(g)
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: You use `x=mod(f(x),n)` but never specify n before.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote n where I should write k. I have edited the post

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem indeed is with your use of the `mod` function. Once you do `x = mod(f(x), k)`, then `x` lives in the ring `Z/kZ`. The same will be true of `g`. Inequalities in that ring don't really make sense, and in particular, `g<k` will get translated to `g<0`. This is because `k=0` mod `k` and when you do algebraic operations, equality checking, inequality checking, etc., both sides are converted to the best ring available. In this case, that ring is `Z/kZ`.

It's probably better to work in the integers the whole time:

```
x = f(x).mod(k)
y = f(f(y)).mod(k)
```

Here is the difference between using `mod` as a function or a method:

```
sage: type(5.mod(3))  # method
<type 'sage.rings.integer.Integer'>
sage: type(mod(5, 3)) # function
<type 'sage.rings.finite_rings.integer_mod.IntegerMod_int'>
```

If I wanted to save this in a Python file suitable for use in Sage, I would do it like this:

```
from sage.rings.all import Integer

def f(x):
    # Make sure to return a Sage Integer.
    return Integer(x**2+1)

def testing(iter=20):
    x=1
    y=x
    i=0
    k=87757
    while i<iter:
        i=i+1
        x=f(x).mod(k)
        y=f(f(y)).mod(k)
        g=(x-y).gcd(k)
        # For debugging:
        # print(x, y, g)
        if 1<g and g<k:
            print(g)
            print(i)
            break
```

You could add more options to your function: allow `k` as an input, `x`, `y`, etc. Anyway, then run `testing(20)`.